# "charset_map" directive is not allowed here in

Tags: nginx

Странным образом возникла проблема при запуске nginx. Что я делаю не так? Вот что мне выдал systemctl status nginx.service

```
nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-07-16 15:19:14 MSK; 3min 48s ago
  Process: 23302 ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14029 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26862 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26860 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14031 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 16 15:19:14 clever systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Jul 16 15:19:14 clever nginx[26862]: nginx: [emerg] "charset_map" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/win-utf:6
Jul 16 15:19:14 clever nginx[26862]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jul 16 15:19:14 clever systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 16 15:19:14 clever systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Jul 16 15:19:14 clever systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jul 16 15:19:14 clever systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Comment: мало ли кому пригодится, в nginx.conf закоментировал строку с подключением файла win-utf, перезагрузил и потом ту строчку раскоментировал и выполнил reload

Comment: Reload при ошибке в конфиге просто ничего не делает. Так что лучше ищите проблему.

Comment: С другой стороны, этот charset_map уже лет 10 никому не нужен.